# Hiding the top line (control) in a repeating table using InfoPath

Tags: infopath, form, list-form, calculated-column-formula, hide-elements

1. I have set up a Data Connection to retrieve the data from a list (such as Time, Price, etc..)
2. I have created a repeating table to have this section in each line.
3. I was using a Formatting to hide the control if the first field (ItemName) is blank.

Everything works properly in the preview but when I publish it the system shows that this rule runs in error and it automatically deletes the entries added in the fields but if I click OK on the error message, I can submit it for the second time without any issues.

What I'm doing wrong?

See screenshot for details.
[image]

It should look like this
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have received the solution and it works smoothly.

Step 1. Go to Data tab. 
Step 2. Go to Default Values 
Step 3. Right click (repeating) group 
Step 4. Choose: Exclude this group from the initial form.

Boom.